# UINavigationController as ModalView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have in my app class UINavigationController (with NIB) and I want to open this as a ModalView.

I do that so: (ColorInfo is just this UINavigationController class)

```
ColorInfo *InfoScreen = [[ColorInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"ColorInfo" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[InfoScreen setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentModalViewController:InfoScreen animated:YES];
```

It displays me an empty UINavigtionController element. Tell me please how could I open ColorInfo (as UINavigationController) in ModalView, where I will be able to navigate through?
I thought I can complete ColorInfo with all pushViewController methods and then open it over another screen in ModalView.

Tell me how to reach this effect.

Comment: did you subclass uinavigationcontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've stated you've inherited UINavigationController in ColorInfo which is not what you want.  You want ColorInfo to be the root view of a UINavigationController like so

```
ColorInfo *InfoScreen = [[ColorInfo alloc] initWithNibName:@"ColorInfo" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]   initWithRootViewController:InfoScreen];
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

I recommend you read the navigation controller documentation for further clarity.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: sorry, gave same answer, didn't see yours :-|
damn, i need to be faster :-)

Comment: But InfoScreen is already UINavigationController and I want to implement there all the pushes of sub controllers. I knew about initWithRootViewController, but it's not what I need, probably. For more clarity in ColorInfo.h I have: `@interface ColorInfo : UINavigationController`

Comment: @Konrad Kolasa You can still do push and pop from the ColorInfo class by calling self.navigationController and using the various functions on that class.  Once you set InfoScreen as the root view controller of a UINavigationController then the navigationController property of your view controller will be usable.  The only reason you would ever want to inherit UINavigationController would be in order to override or extend its current functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Use this with InfoScreen controller and DON'T subclass UINavigationController ...

```
UINavigationController* navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:InfoScreen];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentModalViewController:InfoScreen animated:YES];
```

Comment: Same as in previous post... I want to have ColorInfo already as UINavigationController